# Jupyter notebook not working at all or very slow

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have been using jupyter notebook for Python for a few months now and everything was working perfectly. I downgraded Tornado to 5.1.1 as suggested by people here. I also deleted python all together and conda too. I reinstalled evertyhing but to no avail. Bugs still everywhere. I managed to create a new python environment and managed to start python notebooks from there, but even there, the notebook is very slow compared with the past. The error is simply `Not connected` and also there is ipykernel after python 3 that wasn't there before. Anyone has any idea? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.

1. delete all your previous ipykernels.
2. delete jupyter notebook and tornado.
3. reinstall all of tehm!